# UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication with IdentityServer3

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, openid, identity, identityserver3

I have a project with local Identity users. At some point the IdentityServer3 was installed in this project and uses the same SQL database to authenticate remote users from different projects. Now I want to disable local login page and authenticate users through openid (basically redirect to localhost and back, so my login page looks consistent).
I am having trouble implementing external login callback action that would do my local signin (the similar action to default ExternalLoginCallback). 
Code looks like this:

```
 app.UseExternalSignInCookie();

 app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
            new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                //SignInAsAuthenticationType = "ExternalCookie",
                ClientId = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["client"].ToString(),
                Authority = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ids"].ToString(),
                RedirectUri = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["clienturi"].ToString(),
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["clienturi"].ToString(),
   });
```

But after authenticating my user correctly the callback uri call returns 302 redirect instead of stepping into controller action. I redirects to the main page and authentications starts over again.
[image]

Comment: what does your controller look like? do you need to belong to a certain group to access it?

Comment: My controller is pretty much empty right now, but breakpoint inside is never being hit when called as callbackuri. It seems to me authentication is being rejected somewhere in the middle and request is deemed as anuthorized.

Comment: My controller action is set as Anonymous btw